# How to extract all users information from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0, system-administration

I need to bulk "download" every user we have on Active directory.

I need the email address, location etc.

I have been looking into the PowerShell command "Get-ADuser -Filter", however I need some help getting this to work.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what output do you expect? show some example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) which has several examples as well.

If you want to retrieve every user, you can use an asterisk `*` with the `Filter` parameter. Otherwise, you can filter using a specific property.

You can specify which properties to return using the `Properties` parameter. By default, the cmdlet will only return a default set of properties, which are below

- DistinguishedName
- Enabled
- GivenName
- Name
- ObjectClass
- ObjectGUID
- SamAccountName
- SID
- Surname
- UserPrincipalName

**Example: Get every user with default property set**

`Get-ADUser -Filter *`

**Example: Get every enabled user with default property set**

`Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true'`

**Example: Get every user with specific properties**

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties emailAddress,office,city`

**Example: Get every user with every property**

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *`

**Example: Get every user with every property and export as a CSV**

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Temp\ADUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

**Additional Info**

[Active Directory: Get-ADUser Default and Extended Properties](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, that' is brilliant. Thank you very much.